# datetime: force microsecond output in isoformat()

Tags: python, datetime

I just posted a question about Google Drive date formats, that I actually found a solution to.  Essentially, Google Drive documentation states that it requires dates to be specified in the RFC 3339 format.  However, it requires the full or long format explicitly, even when milliseconds are zero.  Is there a way to force the datetime isoformat() method to output milliseconds, even when zero?  I'd rather not enforce my own datetime specification using strftime, but if the only solution is to use the following strftime format, then so be it.

```
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the  implementation of datetime isoformat():

```
static char *
isoformat_time(PyDateTime_DateTime *dt, char buffer[], int bufflen)
{
    int x;
    int us = DATE_GET_MICROSECOND(dt);

    x = PyOS_snprintf(buffer, bufflen,
                      "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                      DATE_GET_HOUR(dt),
                      DATE_GET_MINUTE(dt),
                      DATE_GET_SECOND(dt));
    assert(bufflen >= x);
    if (us)
        x += PyOS_snprintf(buffer + x, bufflen - x, ".%06d", us);
    assert(bufflen >= x);
    return buffer + x;
}
```

Doesn't look like you can do anything to enforce microseconds in the output string.

Comment: There's now a timespec parameter to isoformat - looks like it will land in 3.6. Discussion here: https://bugs.python.org/issue19475 Commit here: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8d1d7e6816753248768e4cc1c0370221814e9cf1

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3.6+, you can pass the `timespec` parameter to `isoformat()`

The function ends up calling `_format_time`, where you can see the supported values for the parameter:

```
specs = {
    'hours': '{:02d}',
    'minutes': '{:02d}:{:02d}',
    'seconds': '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}',
    'milliseconds': '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:03d}',
    'microseconds': '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:06d}'
}
```

This will force the value to be rendered even if the specific part is zero